# Finding the square root of a permutation cycle

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Find all $\sigma \in S_4$ satisfying $\sigma^2 = (1 2)(3 4)$

By just brute forcing it, I can easily find $\sigma = (1 3 2 4)$ or $\sigma = (1423)$. But is there a more mathematical way of finding these permutation cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to determine the orders of each of the elements of $S_4$.
The square root of $(12)(34)$ must have order $4$ so you only need to check them.
 By the way you should probably change "square" to "square root" in the title.

Comment: Changed the title, thanks. Also using the order is good advice, thanks for that too.